# Get milliseconds of a Specific Date with time

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am getting problem in converting a `Date` into milliseconds

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setLenient(false);

    String oldTime = "2013-06-11 06:40:24"; 
    Date oldDate;

    oldDate = formatter.parse(oldTime);

    Sysout(oldDate.getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is throwing a `Parsing Exception`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss");
```

should be

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Also, I think you should write :

```
oldDate = formatter.parse(oldTime);
```